# “よいか” in the meaning of “listen”?

Tags: grammar, translation, role-language

I’ve encountered this sentence in a novel:

> 「私はもう助からない。だから**よいか**、［名］…」

Followed by some instructions what to do after the speaker’s death.

What is puzzling me is the `よいか` at the end. From the context and also from some translations I’ve found, this would mean something like “Listen!”:

> I can’t be saved any more. So listen, [name]…

That would make perfect sense. But I am unable to figure out, how can this `よいか` carry such meaning. What is it composed of actually? Is the `よい` the plain old `良い` and the `か` is a particle? Even if so, how come that connected this way it becomes a call for an attention?

Even though looking up `よい` is almost hopeless, all the other possible meanings are fit even worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

よいか can be used like  "Are you following?", "Are you ready (for the next words, etc)?", "Do you understand?" etc. Basically it's similar to how English speakers use "okay?". If said *before* an important statement, it's like "Listen."

よいか is rarely used in real-world conversations because it sounds pompous, but some teachers use いいですか all the time at school.